Conditions so that every compact subset of the image is the image of a compact subset of the domain
Question.

Let $X$ be a uniform space, and $Y$ Hausdorff uniform, both complete. Then, for a continuous surjection $f: X\to Y$, under what conditions can we claim: for every compact set $K\subset Y$, there exists a compact set $C\subset X$ such that $f(C)=K$? Do we also need Hausdorffness for $X$ or uniform continuity for $f$?

Background: I'm fascinated by this assertion and proof in the context of Banach spaces. Trying to find a generalized version for it. Thanks in advance.
Update. Currently, I think the following should work.

Let $X,Y$ be uniform spaces, and $f:X\to Y$ open, uniformly continuous, and surjective. Then, for every compact $K\subset Y$, there exists compact $C\in X$, such that $K=f(C)$.

The proof then relies on the concept of totally boundedness for uniform spaces.

For instance, in the case of local homeomorphisms when the spaces are locally compact. If you want to have a non-example, consider two metric spaces where $X$ has discrete metric and $Y=X, f=id$ and $Y$ is not a discrete topological space.

@MoisheKohan I think $f$ at least needs to be a continuous open surjection, ie, a quotient map. Then, if that alone is not enough, perhaps we need the equivalence classes to satisfy certain properties.

@MoisheKohan The fascinating part about that result is it doesn't assume even local compactness of $X$.

Instead of "quotent" you can say "surjective." Your conjecture holds if $X$ is locally compact. I doubt it holds without this assumption.

@MoisheKohan I think if I require $f$ to be open, uniformly continuous, and surjective, then it should be correct. I don't know, though, if a quotient map between uniform spaces is automatically uniformly continuous or not.
